# Why is a parameter to __init__() missing?

Tags: python, multithreading, websocket, python-asyncio, autobahn

#### Summary

I have a client-server application which makes use of Websockets. The backend (server) part is implemented in Python using `autobahn`.

The server, in addition to serving a Websockets endpoint, runs a series of threads which will feed the Websockets channel with data, though a `queue.Queue()`.

One of these threads has a problem: it crashes at a missing parameter and hangs when resolving the exception.

#### Implementation details

The server implementation (cut down to highlight the problem):

```
from autobahn.asyncio.websocket import WebSocketServerProtocol, WebSocketServerFactory
import time
import threading
import arrow
import queue
import asyncio
import json

# backends of components
import dummy

class MyServerProtocol(WebSocketServerProtocol):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print("webserver initialized")
        # global queue to handle updates from modules
        self.events = queue.Queue()
        # consumer
        threading.Thread(target=self.push).start()
        threading.Thread(target=dummy.Dummy().dummy, args=(self.events,)).start()

    def push(self):
        """ consume the content of the queue and push it to the browser """
        while True:
            update = self.events.get()
            print(update)
            if update:
                self.sendMessage(json.dumps(update).encode('utf-8'), False)
                print(update)
            time.sleep(1)


    def worker(self):
        print("started thread")
        while True:
            try:
                self.sendMessage(arrow.now().isoformat().encode('utf-8'), False)
            except AttributeError:
                print("not connected?")
            time.sleep(3)

    def onConnect(self, request):
        print("Client connecting: {0}".format(request.peer))

    def onOpen(self):
        print("WebSocket connection open.")

    def onClose(self, wasClean, code, reason):
        print("WebSocket connection closed: {0}".format(reason))


if __name__ == '__main__':

    factory = WebSocketServerFactory(u"ws://127.0.0.1:9100")
    factory.protocol = MyServerProtocol

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    coro = loop.create_server(factory, '0.0.0.0', 9100)
    loop.run_until_complete(coro)
    loop.run_forever()
```

The `dummy` module imported in the code above:

```
import time
import arrow

class Dummy:
    def __init__(self, events):
        self.events = events
        print("dummy initialized")

    def dummy(self):
        while True:
            self.events.put({
                'dummy': {
                    'time': arrow.now().isoformat()
                }
            })
            time.sleep(1)
```

#### The problem

When running the code above and connecting from a client, I get on the output `webserver initialized` (which proves that the connection was initiated), and `WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:9100/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` on the client.

When debugging the code, I see that the call to `threading.Thread(target=dummy.Dummy().dummy, args=(self.events,)).start()` crashes and the debugger (PyCharm) leads me to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\Lib\asyncio\selector_events.py`, specifically to the line 236

```
# It's now up to the protocol to handle the connection.
except Exception as exc:
    if self._debug:
```

The thread hangs when executing `if self._debug` but I see on the `except`line (thanks to Pycharm) that

```
exc: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'events'
```

#### My question

Why is this parameter missing? It is provided via the `threading.Thread(target=dummy.Dummy().dummy, args=(self.events,)).start()` call.

As a side question: why does the thread hangs on the `if` condition?

#### Notes

- there is never a Traceback thrown by my program (due to the hang)
- removing this thread call resolves the issue (the client connects correctly)

Comment: @Carcigenicate: ahhhh... thank you - you are absolutely right. If you would not mind just turning your comment into an answer I would gladly accept  it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `events` arg is needed for the constructor, not the `dummy` method. I think you meant something more like:

```
d = Dummy(self.events)
threading.Thread(d.dummy).start()
```